# Change ZIndex of an ListBox Element

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

**My Problem**

When I create new elements in my `ListBox` the newer ones overlay the old ones since they don't have the same `ZIndex` and therefore prevent selection. In my `ListBox` I use a transparent `Rectangles` on a `Canvas` as `ItemTemplate` and `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

I want to change the `ZIndex` of all Elements to the same value so the user can pick the element on which he hovers with the mouse.

**Screenshot**

Screenshot 1: How it should work and currently does when ZIndex is correct

[image]

Screenshot 2: What happens when the ZIndex is not correct

[image]

My XAML Code looks like this:

```
<cc:ListBoxNoDragSelection ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}" Background="{DynamicResource  BG}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
                               BorderThickness="0">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas x:Name="MockupCanvas" Background="Transparent">
                    <Canvas.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="New rectangle" Command="{Binding AddNewRectangleToCollectionCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete selected rectangle" Command="{Binding TryDeleteRectangleFromCollectionCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Canvas.ContextMenu>
                </Canvas>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Rectangle.X}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Rectangle.Y}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto" Width="{Binding Rectangle.Width}">
                    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{Binding Rectangle.Name}" Foreground="{DynamicResource Foreground}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Rectangle.Width}" Height="{Binding Rectangle.Height}"  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                               Fill="Transparent" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </cc:ListBoxNoDragSelection>
```

As you can see I try to set the ZIndex to the same value for each rectangle but that doesn not seem to work at all.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your issue from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Members of a Children collection that have equal ZIndex values are rendered in the order in which they appear in the visual tree.

Setting Z-Index can only do so much. Newer items in the collection will by default be rendered on top of the older elements. If you're looking to use mouse positions to select your elements, maybe look into using [Hit Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/hit-testing-in-the-visual-layer) to determine which element you want

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the information. I'll try this when I go back to work.